# Is there a shorter/more efficient way of writing this expression?

Tags: jquery

I have a `nav` with some child `a`-elements. I added a click function to those elements, and want to know, which one was clicked. As there can be a `span` inside (but don't have to) the `a`-tag as well I used this code to get the index:

#### HTML

```
<nav>
    <a href=""><span></span>Link text</a>
    <a href=""><span></span>Link text</a>
</nav>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var items = $('nav > a');

items.click( function(event) {

    var target  = ( $(event.target).is('span') ? $(event.target).parent() : $(event.target) ); 
    var key     = items.index( target );

    console.log( key );

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

So my question is: Is there a better/short/faster way of writing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the click will propagate through the span to the `<a/>` you should be able to just use `$(this).index()`:

```
var items = $('nav > a');

items.click( function(event) {
  var key = $(this).index();
  console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: Argh, didn't thought of the propagation. That's pretty sleek. Thanks a lot.